# How can I passing data UIViewContoller from UIView in swift3

Tags: ios, swift

How can i passing data uiviewController from uiview

I am Using function but it was not working

protocol name is startcalldelegate and function name is startcall

UIView Code

```
protocol StartCallDelegate: class {
func startCall(localNickname :String, remoteNickname :String)}

class CardView: UIView {

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

weak var delegate: CardViewDelegate?
weak var socketdelegate: StartCallDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var UserPhoto: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var UserNickName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var UserAge: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var UserPeople: UILabel!

var localNickname: String = ""
var remoteNickname: String = ""

@IBAction func SendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
    print("SendMessage")

    //print(localNickName)
    //print(UserNickName.text!)
}

@IBAction func SendVideoCall(_ sender: Any) {
    print("SendVideoCall")

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Profile", in: managedObjectContext)
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let objects = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)

        if objects.count > 0 {
            let match = objects[0] as! NSManagedObject
            localNickname = match.value(forKey: "nick") as! String

        } else {
            print("Nothing founded")
        }
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }

    remoteNickname = UserNickName.text!

    socketdelegate?.startCall(localNickname: localNickname, remoteNickname: remoteNickname)
    delegate?.VideoChatSegue()

}
```

}

UIViewcontroller Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewcontroller, StartCallDelegate {
 var localNickname: String = ""
 var remoteNickname: String = ""

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     print(localNickname)
     print(remoteNickname)
}

    func startCall(localNickname: String, remoteNickname: String) {
    print("Action startcall func")
    self.localNickname = localNickname
    self.remoteNickname = remoteNickname
}
```

startCall func not working

Comment: Where you are creating object of this `CardView`?

Comment: @leeyuno bcoz your delegate is nil i guess.

Comment: @NiravD Other ViewController

Comment: @leeyuno In which controller? Add that controller in your question also how that controller is related to this ViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define delegate in viewcontroller' ViewDidLoad

```
 let objOardView = CardView() // this is only test purpose
 objOardView.socketdelegate = self
```

Comment: Add this code in viewcontroller but not working..   T^T

Comment: did you declared  CardView in your controller ?

Comment: Yes, declared CardView in ViewController

Comment: can you add that in comment ?